# joining an always-running thread in python

Tags: python, multithreading

Forgive me if this is a dumb question; I am very new to threading. 
I am running a thread that will finish when I change it's `keeprunning` status like so:

```
class mem_mon(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.keeprunning = True
        self.maxmem = 0
    def run(self):
        while self.keeprunning:
            self.maxmem = max(self.maxmem, ck_mem())
            time.sleep(10)
```

But due to the `sleep` call, I often have to wait a while before they join.  Other than creating a faster loop that checks `keeprunning` more often, is there anything I can do to join the thread more instantaneously?  For example by overriding `__del__` or `join`?

Comment: Use a `threading.Event` or `threading.Condition` object.

Comment: Thanks - that's what I was trying to say, didn't remember there was a separate class for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [threading.Event](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#event-objects) as an time.sleep() you can interrupt.

```
class mem_mon(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.keeprunning = True
        self.maxmem = 0
        self.interrupt = threading.Event()

    def run(self):
        # this loop will run until you call set() on the interrupt
        while not self.interrupt.isSet():
            self.maxmem = max(self.maxmem, ck_mem())

            # this will either sleep for 10 seconds (for the timeout)
            # or it will be interrupted by the interrupt being set
            self.interrupt.wait(10)

mem = mem_mon()
mem.run()

# later, set the interrupt to both halt the 10-second sleep and end the loop
mem.interrupt.set()
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I can think of is the ugliest as well - I once saw how to kill any Thread in Python, in this recipe: http://icodesnip.com/snippet/python/timeout-for-nearly-any-callable - I never used it, using Locks and Queue as needed, but the possibility is there.

Comment: ugly solutions aren't necessary when a mutex event can do it the exact same amount of code

Comment: You're right of course, I just thought that it's worth knowing that there is such a solution. One instance I can think of where I would use it is when working with legacy code - it's easier to just kill some thread than partially rewrite it. But as I said I never used it and I don't know when or if I will. It's just something curious that's worth knowing IMHO :)